# Why (int) (Math.random() * 0xFFFFFFFF) is 0

Tags: java, binary, overflow, bit-manipulation

Is it due to overflow?
But in my understanding, Math.random() gives a number less than 1, the result should be something less than 0xFFFFFFFF.

Comment: Could you please provide the code?

Comment: think about what `0xFFFFFFFF` is, or read my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`0xFFFFFFFF` is `-1`. So,  you multiply `-1` with a value between `0.0` and `1.0` (`1.0` is not included) (according to the java docs of [`Math.random()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%29)). The multiplication would result in a value between `-1.0` (not including) and `0.0`. When you cast it to `int` you end up with a `0` because the decimal values is lost.

Comment: That's not the actual problem. OP thinks he is multiplying the random number with a very large number, but that's not the case.

Comment: Are you saying that `(int) (Math.random() * 100)` will also be `0` all the time??

Comment: Before casting to int, he is multiplying it by a number. So the problem is not in the cast, and your answer is incorrect.

Comment: As I said my first edit was to explain a part of the question and then the edit to go in detail. In my first part I never touched the multiplication part. Hope its fine now?

Comment: I think what you say is ((int) Math.random()) * 0xFFFFFFFF

Comment: @eternay - No. 12 mins ago i said "the edit continues" where I talked about part of the question and this is how I approach

Comment: @Zoe - The second part really makes you feel I am saying - ((int) Math.random()) * 0xFFFFFFFF?

Comment: @Junaid: I believe you. But look at it from other perspective: First you have an answer that doesn't address the actual problem. Then, after relevant answers start to appear, you have an edit taking care of the real problem also. I actually wonder who upvotet this 3x while it was completely irrelevant. I took my downvote away after you had the relevant parts covered.

Comment: @jlordo - When you edit you cannot see who is answering and what are the answers. So I cannot copy. I try to break the problem and solve it. Thats what  did. I was just trying to explain the OP the problem in parts and in detail. Otherwise it could have been - 0xFFFFFFFF is -1 multiply with 0.0 to 1 and you will end up with a 0 because of casting.

Comment: @All - I will keep it in mind from next time. Will not click the post button until everything is there. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 4):

`0xFFFFFFFF` in two's complement is `-1` decimal.

You are right, `Math.random()` returns a number between `0` and `1`. Now assume it's `0.5`. Then you have:

`(int) (0.5 * -1)` which is `(int)(-0.5)` which is `0` when cast to `int`.

Assuming you want to use the largest positive number, use this:

```
(int) (Math.random() * 0x7FFFFFFF)
                         ^
```

or even better

```
(int) (Math.random() * Integer.MAX_VALUE)
```

Comment: Millions of thanks! Good point by 0x7FFFFFFF, it's the maximum for signed int.

Answer (score 1):

```
0xFFFFFFFF = -1
Math.random() takes a value from [0, 1] interval
```

You are multiplying a number that is smaller than `1` with a `-1`. The result is the very same number, but with a negative sign. Casting it to `int` will discard the decimal part and you are left with `0`.

Answer (score -1):

Math.Random returns a double in the form 0.0 to >1.0. So if you cast that to an int, you will have 0. 0 * number = 0

Comment: There is a multiplication happening before the cast. The multiplicand is wrong. To get a random number between `0` and `100` you can write `(int) (Math.random() * 100)` and it will **not** be `0`.